# Google Gadgets and OpenID/OAuth 1.0 Deprecation

Tags: authentication, google-oauth, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Google have deprecated OAuth 1.0 and Open ID and in April 2015 they will be turned off.

We make use of Google Gadgets (both contextual Gadgets and Gadgets embedded in Google sites).  To perform authentication and to identify the users who are making use of the Gadgets we currently use Open ID and signed requests (using OAuth 1.0 signed requests and the opensocial_viewer_id parameter, https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/remote-content#auth using a signature type of SIGNED) from the Gadgets.  The user performs a one-time authentication step and we associate the ID from the Open ID exchange with the email address of the user.  On subsequent requests we verify the signed requests and from the Open ID exchange previously performed we know the email address of the calling user.

The signed requests are made using the following code which adds an OAuth 1.0 signature to the request:

```
function makeSignedRequest(a, b) {
    var c = {};
    c[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
    c[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION] = gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.SIGNED;
    c["OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME"] = "HMAC";
    c[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.GET;
    gadgets.io.makeRequest(a, b, c)
}
```

With the deprecation of these two technologies, its clear a replacement is needed.  Its possible to associate the users ID with their email address using OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect login (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login), so thats the Open ID exchange issue dealt with.  What is not clear is how to proceed going forward with signing requests and that leads to my question:

Will the function above continue to work after April 2015, and will the signature continue to be added as it is now by the container?  Should some other form of authentication be used, or some other form of signing/validating requests from Google Gadgets?

Comment: Thanks for the OpenID Connect link, it's exactly what I've been looking for while updating my gadget

Comment: Well, they didn't stop working :-)